# E-mail's and Exchange's errors in emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I update my Eclipse SDK to last updates (today).

When I launch emulator on 4.0.3, 4.1.2 or 4.2 (Android or Google APIs 15, 16, 17 on any CPU) `e-mail` application is not present in him and `com.android.exchange` generate warnings and errors:

```
12-26 06:20:19.094: D/ExchangeService(6926): Received deviceId from Email app: null
12-26 06:20:19.231: D/ExchangeService(6926): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
12-26 06:20:19.700: D/dalvikvm(6988): GC_CONCURRENT freed 853K, 16% free 5232K/6196K, paused 10ms+9ms, total 250ms
12-26 06:20:21.790: I/GTalkService/c(7089): [AndroidEndpoint@1087613288] connect: acct=1000000, state=CONNECTING
12-26 06:20:24.591: D/ExchangeService(6926): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand,     startingUp = false, running = false
12-26 06:20:24.765: W/ActivityManager(6509): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
12-26 06:20:25.131: D/ExchangeService(6926): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
12-26 06:20:25.182: W/ActivityManager(6509): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
12-26 06:20:25.441: D/dalvikvm(6988): GC_CONCURRENT freed 859K, 16% free 5228K/6204K, paused 14ms+11ms, total 313ms
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d18f10 that was originally bound here
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d18f10 that was originally bound here
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-26 06:20:26.093: E/ActivityThread(6926):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926): null
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d18f10 that was originally bound here
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-26 06:20:26.941: E/StrictMode(6926):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are not accessing a null object. I had this exception in 2.1, 4.1, and 4.2. All because I was accessing a null object.